# Data table gets pushed down

Tags: html, css

My table with data from the database gets pushed down and sticks to my footer. I don't really know how to get it up and not stick to my footer.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table style='border: solid 1px grey; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: -20px;'><th>Film titel</th><th>Film genre</th>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>"  .   $row["film_titel"]. "<td> " . $row["genre"]. "</td></td></tr><br>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Footer CSS:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#619b28+0,427768+100 */
    background: #619b28; /* Old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #619b28 0%, #427768 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#619b28', endColorstr='#427768',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Comment: remove bottom: 0 from the css.

Comment: How come when I output data the table gets so low? Is there anything to do about it?

Comment: May not be related to your problem, but `<th>` elements should also be enclosed in `<tr>`.

Comment: Thank you. Will look into that.

Comment: Now I also noticed that your `<td>` elements are inside each other, first close the left one before opening another. And also there is no reason to put `<br>` after `</tr>`. You may try using https://validator.w3.org/ to help you find HTML mistakes.

Comment: Thank you, again! The problem lies with the <td> elements.

Comment: I think it more likely that the problem was with the stray <br>, to be honest.

Comment: I deleted that, but still had the problem. Now it's alright.

Comment: @Russell If that solved the issue, I posted the comment as an answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors in your HTML.

- `<th>` elements should also be enclosed in `<tr>`
- your `<td>` elements are inside each other, first close the left one before opening another
- there is no reason to put `<br>` after `</tr>`.

You may try using [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/) to help you find HTML mistakes.